# Notation confusion in time-derivative: $g_t(X,X)=g_t^{ij}X_jX_i=\sum X_i^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ a Riemannian manifold and $X$ a vector field. I know that  $g(X,X)=g^{ij}X_jX_i=X^iX_i$. Some authors use $g(X,X)=\sum X_i^2$ instead. That was Ok until I wanted to compute the time-derivative of length of vector field $X$ w.r.t time-dependent metric $g_t$.

In the first notation $g_t^{ij}X_jX_i$, square  norm of vector field easily seen to be time-dependent but in later notation $\sum X_i^2$ seems is $t$-independent. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion
$$ g(X, X) = \sum_i X_i^2$$
is definitely wrong, or only holds at the origin of a normal coordinate. When you have a family of metrics you have to use $g_{ij}X^iX^j$ and calculate also $\partial_t g_{ij}$.

**Edit** Another instance where $g(X, X) = \sum_i X_i^2$ makes sense is when $X =\sum_i  X_i e_i$, where $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ is a local orthonormal frame. Since you mentioned a family of metric, in Ricci flow sometimes one might also flow the initial orthonormal frame to obtain a family of orthonormal frame (see e.g. 6.1 in [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642162855))
$$ \{ e_1(t), \cdots, e_n(t)\}.$$
Thus even when $X$ is a fixed vector fields on $M$,
$$X = \sum _i X_i(t) e_i(t)$$
and $X_i$ depends on $t$. So
$$ g_t(X, X) = \sum_i X_i^2 (t) $$
also depends on $t$.

Comment: It is ok if the components of $X$ are with respect to an orthonormal frame of vector fields.

Comment: But you’re right that if you are differentiating with respect to time, it’s best to fix the coordinates or frame of vector fields and write the metric using $g_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks, @Deane. I've edited the post.

Comment: What about $tr_g(h_{ij})=\langle g,h\rangle$? I have seen that $d/dt \ tr_g(h_{ij})=\langle d/dt g_t,h\rangle$, but why we don't take derivative of $\langle.,.\rangle$?

Comment: $\operatorname{tr}_g (h_{ij}) = g^{ij}h_{ij}$. So the derivative is $(\partial_t g^{ij}) h_{ij}$. (It is easier if you could provide reference, so that I don't have to guess your notations) @C.F.G